# name: 'LinkAccountError', [next-auth][error][adapter_error_linkAccount]

Tags: mongodb, next.js, instagram, prisma, next-auth

I am making a sign up page with 3 providers (Twitter, Facebook and Instagram) using next-auth and prisma with mongoDB. The issue appears when I try to sign up with any of the providers. I think the prisma schema is the problem. Here is the error that I receive:

```
Invalid `p.account.create()` invocation in
C:\...\node_modules\@next-auth\prisma-adapter\dist\index.js:19:42

  16 },
  17 updateUser: ({ id, ...data }) => p.user.update({ where: { id }, data }),
  18 deleteUser: (id) => p.user.delete({ where: { id } }),
→ 19 linkAccount: (data) => p.account.create({
       data: {
         provider: 'instagram',
         type: 'oauth',
         providerAccountId: '62921xxxxxx98535',
         access_token: 'IGQVJYdU...',
         user_id: 178xxxx,
         ~~~~~~~
         userId: '63e2538xxxx'
       }
     })

Unknown arg `user_id` in data.user_id for type AccountUncheckedCreateInput. Did you mean `userId`? Available args:
type AccountUncheckedCreateInput {
  id?: String
  userId: String
  type: String
  provider: String
  providerAccountId: String
}
```

I have red all the documentations about, chatGPT also didn't help much. The prisma schema looks like this:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String  @map("provider_account_id")
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
  @@map("accounts")
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sessionToken String   @unique @map("session_token")
  userId       String   @db.ObjectId
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("sessions")
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
  @@map("verificationtokens")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `user_id` parameter while creating an account, but there is no  field named `user_id` in the Account model in your schema file.

If you need to pass `user_id` while creating an account then you need to define it in the Account model as well.